# Error: invalid type(list) for variable when using lm() in looping

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to loop linear regression but I got an error

```
invalid type (list) for variable 'uji[1]'
```

this my sample data looks like

```
 obs        1        2        3        4        5
1 20.6 25.56560 26.10068 26.58787 26.79679 26.83781
2 23.2 25.69174 26.24989 26.68043 26.86044 26.88161
3 25.0 26.19047 26.53224 26.81343 26.95374 26.98031
4 27.4 26.95023 26.87636 26.98147 27.08031 27.11273
5 28.8 27.60605 27.19273 27.12003 27.16689 27.17638
```

here my code

```
while (i <= 170 ) {
  lmTemp <- lm(uji[1] ~ as.matrix(uji[i+1]), data = uji )
  print(lmTemp)
}
```

here I produce my sample data

```
    structure(list(obs = c(20.6, 23.2, 25, 27.4, 28.8, 29.2, 30, 
29.4, 29.4, 29.2), `1` = c(25.5656043, 25.69174497, 26.19046783, 
26.95023182, 27.60604654, 28.1500282, 28.39544774, 28.46275197, 
28.1386405, 28.0857899), `2` = c(26.1006802, 26.24988827, 26.53224483, 
26.87635776, 27.19273143, 27.47435801, 27.64108561, 27.74561886, 
27.75525461, 27.81204711), `3` = c(26.58786936, 26.68043093, 
26.81343342, 26.98147499, 27.12002534, 27.27697121, 27.40281989, 
27.51976281, 27.66225506, 27.76474436), `4` = c(26.79678986, 
26.86044418, 26.95373572, 27.08031439, 27.16689011, 27.28719094, 
27.40603181, 27.50735314, 27.62035416, 27.69831611), `5` = c(26.83781478, 
26.88161362, 26.98030702, 27.11272554, 27.17637986, 27.27463527, 
27.39070221, 27.49406749, 27.58414711, 27.61977018)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried reading it as a numeric, and as a data.frame, which is what most other threads suggested, but neither worked.

Comment: I think what the error is saying is that your dependent variable is a list. Try using `uji[[1]]`. If this does not work, please provide a reproducible sample of your data set on which I run your code and debug.

Comment: I did, but it still get an error 

lmTemp <- lm(uji[[1] ~ as.matrix(uji[i+1]), data = uji )
Error: unexpected '~' in "lmTemp <- lm(uji[[1] ~"

Comment: Could you please add to your question the code to create a sample data on which I can run your loop?

Comment: i just added this command to produce the sample data

Comment: It looks like this thread has been closed. I hope the other thread has been helpful.